# Angular 7 while build StaticInjectorError

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I am able to build and serve the application in dev server.But coming to the production build,the application is resulting in following errors.

Any suggestions would be helpful.Thanks in advance.If any additional information,please do let me know.

angular version - 7.2.3

main.272e7817336e789a3feb.js:1 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[e -> e]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[e -> e]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for e!
    at e.get (main.272e7817336e789a3feb.js:1)
    at main.272e7817336e789a3feb.js:1
    at e (main.272e7817336e789a3feb.js:1)
    at e.get (main.272e7817336e789a3feb.js:1)
    at main.272e7817336e789a3feb.js:1
    at e (main.272e7817336e789a3feb.js:1)
    at e.get (main.272e7817336e789a3feb.js:1)
    at Pg (main.272e7817336e789a3feb.js:1)
    at main.272e7817336e789a3feb.js:1
    at Ig (main.272e7817336e789a3feb.js:1)

Comment: please provide full error Details

Comment: use ng serve --prod, You will get know where is the error, You might missed some Module missed to app module

Comment: Looks like some dependency injection issue but can you add more details here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saying that you have injected service directly into component's constructor. Instead of directly injecting in component you need to first add service in module.

Add it in module's providers array. Then you can use it in component.

Ex: providers: [ServiceName]

Comment: Thanks for the response.Actually providedIn to root in the service itself Instead of using in module providers

Comment: Thanks for response devang. cookie-service is not mentioned in the providers caused the error